# Expected value of an exponential of a gaussian random variable

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

$$E (Y_t)=E(e^{X_t}) = E(e^{N(X_0e^{at};\frac{b^2}{2a}(e^{2at}-1)}) =\text{ ?}$$

Knowning that

$$X_t \sim N\left[X_0e^{at};\frac{b^2}{2a}(e^{2at}-1)\right]$$

$$X_t= aX_t \, dt+b \, dB_t$$

The processes are standard brownian motions.
Thank you

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? Note that for any normal random variable $X$ the expectation $$\mathbb{E}e^{cX}, \qquad c \in \mathbb{R},$$ can be calculated explicitly; see e.g. wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry do you mean it should become $E(e^{\int_R^.N-pdf})$ of the normal pdf calculated on those parameters?

Comment: No, I mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions).

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it, so the $E(Y_t)$ is the moment generating function itself (given that mu and sigma). Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{E}Y_t$ is the moment generating function and -as I said- it can be calculated explicitly for Gaussian random variables.